# What's going on with my tor? - decoding logs

Tags: log

I run an onion site and I try to monitor logs. It fails every time because I don't know what pops out when.

Please help me decode these which are from this week.

1. something fails.

   ```
   [warn] connection_edge_process_relay_cell (at origin) failed.
   ```
2. something timed out.

   ```
   [notice] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit ##### (a Hidden service: Connecting to rendezvous point 4-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 60000ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 4 guards are live.
   ```
3. the what now?

   ```
    [notice] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit ##### (a Measuring circuit timeout 3-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 60000ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 4 guards are live. [# similar message(s) suppressed in last 3600 seconds]
   ```
4. less grass mowing more english please?

   ```
   [notice] Your Guard ######## ($################################) is failing more circuits than usual. Most likely this means the Tor network is overloaded. Success counts are 1##/2##. Use counts are 8#/8#. 1## circuits completed, 0 were unusable, 1 collapsed, and 3 timed out. For reference, your timeout cutoff is 60 seconds.
   ```
5. nothing's changed, bruh. just you...

   ```
   [notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 1# timeouts and 1### buildtimes.
   ```